# (Unity3D-Android) Failded to build, always

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, android-build

First of all : sorry for bad english. I'm trying to build android game with unity3D game engine but always get those two errors.

This one is first.

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
C:\Android\build-tools\25.0.3\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "C:/Android\platforms\android-16\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages android.support.v7.appcompat -S "C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity – Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res"

stderr[
C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-ldltr-v21\values-ldltr-v21.xml:3: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:17: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:216: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:218: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:176: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:189: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.EditText'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:10: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:264: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:276: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Title'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml:8: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml:11: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginEnd'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml:14: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml:17: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml:20: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml:21: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml:25: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml:24: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml:28: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml:31: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml:34: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentEnd'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml:38: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toEndOf'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml:37: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml:41: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml:45: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml:44: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml:49: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml:48: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:9: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:11: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:12: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:13: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:14: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:15: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:16: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:18: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:27: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:31: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:34: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:35: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:39: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:43: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:45: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:47: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:53: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:55: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.

C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity � Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:57:<message truncated>
```

And this one is secound :

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: Build failed with errors.
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x001b9] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:162 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00050] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:83 
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

I'm using JDK 1.8 and targeting to API Level 16. I already have appcompat v7 25.3.1 in Plugins/Android . I get this error always but only when trying to build apk. It is so depressing... I am very new to android, building only windows games before and this never happend before.
Thanks.
 -Garrom

Comment: What is your Unity version?

Comment: If it matters so much I'm using Unity3D 2017.1.1f1. @Shaman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your error log, i can see that you're using **Android SDK Build-tools** version: 25.0.3 which is lower than the minimal version required to compile the support library. In order for it to successfully compile, **Android SDK Build-tools** version must be equal to or higher than the support library version. So just update your **Android SDK Build-tools** to 26.0.0 or higher.

Comment: Thanks for tip. I updated Android SDK Build tools but now i'm getting this error. But at least we are getting somewhere.                                           `Win32Exception: ApplicationName='C:/...\aapt.exe', CommandLine='package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "C:/...\android-16\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages android.support.v7.appcompat -S "C:\Users\Garrom\Desktop\Files\WarCity – Android\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.0.0\res"', CurrentDirectory='Temp/StagingArea', Native error= Cannot find file`

Comment: What is your **Android SDK Build-tools** version?

Comment: Lastest avalible, 27.0.3. Before, I was using SDK Manager by B4A but after using older version (and official sdk manager) i found several packages missing or broken. Maybe errors vanish if i repair those packs

Comment: Damn, I forgot to mention you @Shaman, again. By the way, i really don't understand this "appcompact" much, If i get it, it is something like big archive with android resourcess, right ? So Appcompact 25 means it will add compability with with API level 25 and can be used on any API level OR it adds compability with other API levels but can be used only on level 25 ? Just asking because i'm trying to use appcompact 25 on API level 16.

Comment: and NOW i'm getting original error again. Holy cow what magic is this .. oh, yes , this is reason why i hate java so much. I'm doing something wrong for sure but what ? Why nobody make step-by-step tutorial how to prepare project for android export ? @Shaman